# How to control spam in Forms in Joomla

Tags: joomla

I have a website running in Joomla 2.5.9.

On a particular page I have create a simple form which retrieves certain information from the user and sends the information via Email to admin.

This form is using math captcha.

I have added a hidden field to this form and checking if this hidden field is filled. If yes then reject the form.

The problem is that the admin is receiving at least 200 spam Emails ( per day ) from this particular form.

No other form on that website is getting spam Email.

Can anyone tell me know how I can reduce the number of spam Emails.
OR
Is there any free plugin which handles form creation + spam handling + math captcha in Joomla?

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: Did you consider the core captcha plugin

Answer (score 3):

1. Use session token in form (see docs: [How to add CSRF anti-spoofing to forms](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_add_CSRF_anti-spoofing_to_forms))
2. Check out [Captcha plugins in Extensions directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/captcha)
3. Best anti-spam is a custom solution.
   I added mechanisms to check for duration in which form has been filled in and submitted, set maximum retries and added backend form validation. This reduced spam to 0, but I'm aware I'll have to come with additional things when situation changes.

Key question is: What is are the differences in behavior between a person that wants to contact you and a spambot script?

Answer (score 0):

Is this the only form using math captcha? If your using anti-spam-'tools' and get a lot of spam, than the tools seem to be bad.

It also often helps to add a small, static question, which can simply be answered by the users like i.e. 'every 2nd letter of the domain' or 'name of the headcoach'. This is so specific, that bots normally don't know, what to insert. **This should just be an addon to the normal anti-spam!**